# Stanford Classifier: generating model for on the fly classification (eg big data stream)?

Tags: classification, stanford-nlp

I went through the tutorial on training data as per http://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier#The_Stanford_Classifier

How would I go about using the trained model on larger big data that can be processed as a stream?

The output from the classifier is just a report on test / train data. I would expect some kind of json model output that can be reused on other data.

PS
Looks like the Stanford NER Classifier (eg generating a model file and using that file on new data) has this capability https://blogs.nd.edu/wilkens-group/2013/10/15/training-the-stanford-ner-classifier-to-study-nineteenth-century-american-fiction/